Override default screen mirroring on Android tablet?
I am attempting to stream video from an android tablet, via its hdmi out port. However, the tablet (https://www.tripltek.com/product-page/tripltek9) has some interesting default behavior. There appears to be an hdmi display only when the hdmi port is not in use. I've determined this via the following block of code:
DisplayManager displayManager = (DisplayManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
Display[] displays = displayManager.getDisplays();
for (Display display : displays) {
    if (display.getName().contains("HDMI")) { 
        //do something with the HDMI display
    }
}

Any ideas as to why the hdmi display and built-in display are being "combined" when an external device is connected? Or ideas as to how I could programmatically circumvent this?
Some additional information, if useful:
The android broadcast intent "android.media.action.HDMI_AUDIO_PLUG" correctly indicates whether an external device is plugged in vs not. Additionally, the entire tablet screen gets displayed on the external device. The issue is specifically that the hdmi display is not a separate entity from the built-in display, at least not in the DisplayManager, so I cannot selectively show elements on the external device.
